# Resample dataframe based on time ranges, ignoring date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample my data to get sums. This resampling needs to be based solely on time. I want to group the times in 6 hours, so regardless of the date I will get 4 sums.

My df looks like this:

```
                     booking_count
date_time                        
2013-04-04 08:32:25             58
2013-04-04 18:43:11             1
2013-30-04 12:39:15             52
2013-14-05 06:51:33             99
2013-01-06 23:59:17             1
2013-03-06 19:37:25             42
2013-27-06 04:12:01             38
```

With this example data, I expect the get the following results:

```
00:00:00            38
06:00:00           157
12:00:00            52
18:00:00            43
```

To get around the date issue, I tried to keep only the time values:

```
df['time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date_time']).time
new_df = df[['time', 'booking_bool']].set_index('time').resample('360min').sum()
```

Unfortunately, this was to no avail. How do I go about getting my required results? Is `resample()` even suitable for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `resample()` is a good method to do this because you need to groupby based on hours independently of the day. Maybe you can try using `cut` using a custom `bins` parameter, and then a usual `groupby`

```
bins = np.arange(start=0, stop=24+6, step=6)
group = df.groupby(pd.cut(
            df.index.hour,
            bins, right=False,
            labels=pd.date_range('00:00:00', '18:00:00', freq='6H').time)
        ).sum()

group
#           booking_count
# 00:00:00  38
# 06:00:00  157
# 12:00:00  52
# 18:00:00  44
```